# Bootstrap 3 thumbnails: properly frame image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3 i want design a row with 2 thumbnail so, following the documentation, i have code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="link" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="link" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What i obtain is the html page (i post an image excerpt) below:
[image]

How can i obtaine a frame like the one in the bootstrap documentation (that properly enclose the images)?:

[image]

Note: my image dimension are 150px x 150px

Comment: Hi there tom, did you fixed your issue ?

Answer (score 10):

.thumbnail class is set as block, change it to inline-block will do the trick

```
.thumbnail {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

remove inline css in image markup `<img src="link" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">`

style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"

This override the 'responsive' .css

Also, you should search bootstrap for '[thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails)' witch is a css construction for displaying like bootstrap. It seems your 'outter' class="thumbnails" is missing

**Code [pasted from bootstrap v2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails)**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img alt="300x200" data-src="holder.js/300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Action</a> <a class="btn" href="#">Action</a></p>
              </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

**Code pasted [from bootstrap v3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="300x200" data-src="holder.js/300x200" style="">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

You also have to take note that the images in your example are smaller than the available space. Bootstrap won't make it bigger by default.

[image]

As per version 3, the way bootstrap did it is by applying a fixed height and 100% width to their thumbnail images.

```
display: block;
height: 180px;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: i have removed the inline css "style" but that no resolve my problem. Anyway i have seen the incline css "style" in boostrap 3 documentation in the section Thumbnails - Custom section

Comment: I use bootstrap 3 and not bootstrap 2  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Comment: Well, i started in the wrong direction with the wrong version of your bootstrap framework. Can you provide a 'live' example so i can study your case further?

Comment: In bootstrap 3 documentation, they 'modified' the basic layout to **show** examples. They forced inline the width and height of the image in another purpose.

Comment: Essentially my code is structured as in the documentation. I've tried to remove the inline css style in the img tag but this no resolve the problem

Comment: I notices your html markups are OK (like bootstrap). Has mentioned before, i won't be able to help you more without a 'live' example.